# Cannot redeclare config() error in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, config, php, redeclare

I am getting the error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare config() (previously declared in.../basics.php:58, in live server. It works fine in my local server but when i uploaded the site to live server, i got the fatal error.
I checked if the config() was declared multiple times but it's only declared once in basics.php file.
The naming conventions are also followed, as it is working fine in local server. It only displays such error in live site.
Please suggest solution for this.

Help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a full error text, along with with a file/line number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set $uses to array() and $autoRender to false as follows will solve this problem

```
   class IndexController extends AppController
    {

        public $uses = array();
        public $autoRender = false;

        public function index()
        {
            echo 'test';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error running Apache, and it ended up being related to my `.htaccess` files being ignored - I had been reconfiguring Apache, and had accidentally set `AllowOverride` to `None` in my config file, which was somehow causing this error.

So, in brief, in either your http.conf or one of your site configs, make sure the AllowOverride in your relevant Directory section is set to `All` (or something other than `None`), here's mine:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yes, this is True. And before you have to enable mod_rewrite, for example in Ubuntu

`sudo a2enmod rewrite; sudo service apache2 restart` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if "basics.php" was included multiple times. You can prevent it by using `include_once/require_once` instead of `include/require`.

But this doesn't explain why it's working on your local webserver.

Comment: yea, its the same code in local and live but its works fine in local but showing error in live, and i've checked for multiple redeclaration of config() and basics.php, but its only declared once and included once, but still i'm facing this problem

Comment: For me, this was it. As simple as an additional require, instead of require_once in my ROOT/index.php: require CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'basics.php';

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody happens to search for this.

I had the same error on a windows 2003 server with cakephp 1.3.11 installed. In my case it was because I had a typo in one class association declaration.

I had defined a *Client* class with a hasOne association to a Account class. There I had wrongly typed the className property to *Client* which created a loop and resulted in the *Cannot redeclare config() error in cakePHP*.

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP version. that errors happens when you use PHP version 5.4 which is more stricter than 5.3

open your cake/bootstrap.php and make changes to make sure every file loaded once with function 'require_once'. The code will be like this:

```
require_once CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'basics.php';
require CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'config' . DS . 'paths.php';
require_once LIBS . 'object.php';
require_once LIBS . 'inflector.php';
require_once LIBS . 'configure.php';
require_once LIBS . 'set.php';
require_once LIBS . 'cache.php';
Configure::getInstance();
require_once CAKE . 'dispatcher.php';
```